# Why is מועד the only סדר משניות that is singular?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, mishna

In שבת לא. it brings the names of the 6 sederim of משניות. All of them are plural (זרעים נשים נזיקין קודשים טהרות) apart from מועד that is singular.

Does anyone know is this issue is dealt with anywhere?

(Asked by R' Yaakov Boruch (Jamie) Davila שליט'א)

Comment: Josh Silverblatt, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here! It's helpful to have the same question expressed in multiple ways, so that people googling for this information have a greater chance of finding it, one way or the other. I hope the answers already posted are helpful to you, and I hope you'll stick around and keep reading and sharing questions and answers!